# Why does second dropdown list resets when first dropdown is being changed

Tags: r, shiny

here is part of code I have written, and the problem I am having is that after selecting both player 1 and player, if I wish to change player 1 again, player 2 also resets. I had to make Player 2's input dependent on Player1 because I do not want the user to be able to select the same player for both the dropdowns. Here is my code:

`server.R`

```
shinyServer <- function(input, output) {

  # Creates the first drop down menu through which the user can select the first player.
  output$firstdropdown <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("player1", label = "Choose Player 1:", choices = winrateRole(input$role)$player,
                   selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL)
  })

  # Creates the second drop down menu. User cannot select the same player he/she select as the first player.
  output$seconddropdown <- renderUI({
    all.choices <- winrateRole(input$role)$player
    without.player1 <- all.choices[which(all.choices != input$player1)]
    selectizeInput("player2", label = "Choose Player 2:", choices = without.player1,
                   selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL)
  })
```

`ui.R`

```
shinyUI <- fluidPage(

         navbarPage(strong("Test1"),
           tabPanel("Overview"),
           tabPanel("Tab1",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 uiOutput("firstdropdown"),
                 br(),
                 uiOutput("seconddropdown")
               )
    ))
)
```

`winrateRole`

```
winrateRole <- function(role) {
  blue.role <- paste0("blue", role)
  blue <- league.data %>%
    group_by_(blue.role) %>%
    summarise(winrate.blue = round((sum(bResult) / n() * 100), digits = 2)) %>%
    arrange_(blue.role) %>%
    select(player = blue.role, winrate.blue)

  red.role <- paste0("red", role)
  red <- league.data %>%
    group_by_(red.role) %>%
    summarise(winrate.red = round((sum(rResult) / n() * 100), digits = 2)) %>%
    arrange_(red.role) %>%
    select(player = red.role, winrate.red)
  return (left_join(blue, red))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you recreate the whole input everytime the value of the first select changes.

In this case you want to use the updateInput method which only changes the values you want but leaves the rest unchanged. Unfortunatly updateSelectizeInput seems to reset selected every time choises are changed so you need to save the value of the input in a reactivevariable.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  current_selection <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  observeEvent(input$player2, {
    current_selection(input$player2)
  })
  # update player 2
  observeEvent({
    input$player1
  },{
    all.choices <- winrateRole
    without.player1 <- all.choices[which(all.choices != input$player1)]
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "player2",
      session = session,
      selected = current_selection(),
      choices = without.player1
    )
  },
  ignoreInit = FALSE
  )
  output$firstdropdown <- renderUI({ 
    selectizeInput(
      "player1", 
      label = 
        "Choose Player 1:", 
      choices = winrateRole, 
      selected = NULL, 
      multiple = FALSE,
      options = NULL) })
  # Creates the second drop down menu. User cannot select the same player he/she select as the first player. 
  output$seconddropdown <- renderUI({ 
    selectizeInput(
      "player2", 
      label = "Choose Player 2:", 
      choices = winrateRole, 
      selected = NULL, 
      multiple = FALSE,
      options = NULL)})
}
```

** ui.R**

```
  shinyUI <- fluidPage(


navbarPage(strong("Test1"),
           tabPanel("Overview"),
           tabPanel("Tab1",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        uiOutput("firstdropdown"), 
                        br(), 
                        uiOutput("seconddropdown")
                    ))
)
```

Comment: How would that work? I thought we cannot use input in the ui.R file.

Comment: Sorry you are changed the Code to Work with the other Input

Comment: I am getting the error `updateSelectInput: argument "session" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Sorry, the session parameter is an optional parameterthat you can add to you server function and the you just need to put `session = session` in the `updateInput`. Changed the code above to incorporate this.

Comment: Tried it out, even though there are no errors now, the issue is still there- The dropdown 2 is still resetting when I change dropdown 1.

Comment: or does the selection `player1` have any effects on the `input$role`variable?

Comment: So it seams updateSelectizeInput doesn't really work as documented. You must save the current value in a reactive Varaible. I have updated the code now with a work version for me I have removed the dependencies of `input$role` but that shouldn't be any problem for you too put it back in. Thats not were the problem was.

Comment: Still the same issue :/ 
I have updated the question with the winrateRole function. The player 1 is dependent on role- For different role, there is a different dataframe of players.