# Excel-like filtering in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have data of the following format:

```
   Process       Class Category Template Company
1        A      Master Software       ZZ   Apple
2        B    Addendum Hardware       AA Samsung
3        C       Other Hardware       BB   Nokia
4        D      Master Software       CC    Moto
5        E    Addendum Services       ZZ      Mi
6        F Transaction Services       AA OnePlus
7        G      Master Software       BB   Apple
8        H Transaction     Tele       CC Samsung
9        I Transaction Hardware       ZZ   Nokia
10       J    Addendum     Tele       AA    Moto
```

My aim is to create a list of four selectInputs based on *class*, *category*, *template* and *company* and filter *process* using the same.

I have been able to do linear filteration dynamically, as in, in any one specified direction. For example,
on selecting class = "Master", selectInput for Category has choices = "Software".

What I'm attempting now is to create something similar to an Excel filter, where I can select any selectInput in any order and the remaining select inputs should dynamically only have values that reflect my previous choices.

I have the logic down, but I'm facing difficulty preventing selectInputs that have already been selected from re-initializing due to reactivity.

Code:

```
 cldcheck_ctd <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$classdrop))
  {cld <- -1}else if(input$classdrop != 0)
  {cld <- 6}else{cld <- 0}
})

cldcheck_td <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$classdrop))
  {cld <- -1}else if(input$classdrop != 0)
  {cld <- 6}else{cld <- 0}
})

cldcheck_sd <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$classdrop))
  {cld <- -1}else if(input$classdrop != 0)
  {cld <- 6}else{cld <- 0}
})

ctdcheck_cld <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$categorydrop))
  {ctd <- -1}else if(input$categorydrop != 0)
  {ctd <- 6}else{ctd <- 0}

})

ctdcheck_td <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$categorydrop))
  {ctd <- -1}else if(input$categorydrop != 0)
  {ctd <- 6}else{ctd <- 0}

})

ctdcheck_sd <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$categorydrop))
  {ctd <- -1}else if(input$categorydrop != 0)
  {ctd <- 6}else{ctd <- 0}

})

tdcheck_cld <- reactive({if(is.null(input$templatedrop))
{td <- -1}else if(input$templatedrop != 0)
{td <- 6}else{td <- 0}

})

tdcheck_ctd <- reactive({if(is.null(input$templatedrop))
{td <- -1}else if(input$templatedrop != 0)
{td <- 6}else{td <- 0}

})

tdcheck_sd <- reactive({if(is.null(input$templatedrop))
{td <- -1}else if(input$templatedrop != 0)
{td <- 6}else{td <- 0}

})

sdcheck_cld <- reactive({if(is.null(input$supplierdrop))
{sd <- -1}else if(input$supplierdrop != 0)
{sd <- 6}else{sd <- 0}

})

sdcheck_ctd <- reactive({if(is.null(input$supplierdrop))
{sd <- -1}else if(input$supplierdrop != 0)
{sd <- 6}else{sd <- 0}

})

sdcheck_td <- reactive({if(is.null(input$supplierdrop))
{sd <- -1}else if(input$supplierdrop != 0)
{sd <- 6}else{sd <- 0}

})

output$class <- renderUI({
  result <- first_search()
  if(ctdcheck_cld() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$SCM.Category == input$categorydrop,]
  }

  if(tdcheck_cld() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$Contract.Template == input$templatedrop,]
  }

  if(sdcheck_cld() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name == input$supplierdrop,]
  }

  y <- unique(result$Contract.Class)
  dropdown('classdrop', y, value = 0)
})

output$category <- renderUI({
  result <- first_search()

  if(cldcheck_ctd() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$Contract.Class == input$classdrop,]
  }

      if(tdcheck_ctd() > 0)
      {
        result <- result[result$Contract.Template == input$templatedrop,]
      }

      if(sdcheck_ctd() > 0)
      {
        result <- result[result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name == input$supplierdrop,]
      }
  y <- unique(result$SCM.Category)
  dropdown('categorydrop', y, value = 0)
})

output$template <- renderUI({
  result <- first_search()

  if(ctdcheck_td() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$SCM.Category == input$categorydrop,]
  }

  if(cldcheck_td() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$Contract.Class == input$classdrop,]
  }

    if(sdcheck_td() > 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name == input$supplierdrop,]
    }
  y <- unique(result$Contract.Template)
  dropdown('templatedrop', y, value = 0)
})

output$supplier <- renderUI({
  result <- first_search()

  if(ctdcheck_sd() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$SCM.Category == input$categorydrop,]
  }

  if(tdcheck_sd() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$Contract.Template == input$templatedrop,]
  }

  if(cldcheck_sd() > 0)
  {
    result <- result[result$Contract.Class == input$classdrop,]
  }
  y <- unique(result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name)
  dropdown('supplierdrop', y, value = 0)
})
```

*first_search()* is a function that returns the table in the format as shown above.

*dropdown* is a Semantic-UI widget that works exactly similar to selectInput. *value = 0* means that the widget is initialized with a value of 0.

Thank you!

Comment: To see how to dynamicly update selectInput look at my answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641901/create-variable-conditionally-by-group-in-r-write-function/47642019#47642019
and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493062/why-does-second-dropdown-list-resets-when-first-dropdown-is-being-changed/47494147#47494147

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by using global variables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use global variables**.

Assuming that you have one selectInput with `id = 'classdrop'`, create a global variable `classdropvalue` and set it to `input$classdrop` within a reactive function.

With respect to the problem above,
server.R:

```
cldvalue <- 0
ctdvalue <- 0
tdvalue <- 0
sdvalue <- 0
server <- function(input, output){
  cld <- 0 
  ctd <- 0
  td <- 0
  sd <- 0

  cldcheck <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$classdrop))
    {cld <- 0}else if(input$classdrop != 0)
    {cld <- 6 
    cldvalue <<- input$classdrop
    return(cld)}else{cld <- 0}
  })

  ctdcheck <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$categorydrop))
    {ctd <- 0}else if(input$categorydrop != 0)
    {ctd <- 6
     ctdvalue <<- input$categorydrop
     return(ctd)}else{ctd <- 0}

  })

  tdcheck <- reactive({if(is.null(input$templatedrop))
  {td <- 0}else if(input$templatedrop != 0)
  {td <- 6
   tdvalue <<- input$templatedrop
   return(td)}else{td <- 0}

  })

  sdcheck <- reactive({if(is.null(input$supplierdrop))
  {sd <- 0}else if(input$supplierdrop != 0)
  {sd <- 6
   sdvalue <<- input$supplierdrop
   return(sd)}else{sd <- 0}

  })
#   
#   output$filter <- renderText({
#     paste(cldcheck(), ctdcheck(), tdcheck(), sdcheck())})


  output$class <- renderUI({input$clear
    result <- first_search()
        if(ctdcheck() != 0)
        {
          result <- result[result$SCM.Category == input$categorydrop,]
        }

        if(tdcheck() != 0)
        {
          result <- result[result$Contract.Template == input$templatedrop,]
        }

        if(sdcheck() != 0)
        {
          result <- result[result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name == input$supplierdrop,]
        }

    y <- unique(result$Contract.Class)
    dropdown('classdrop', y, value = cldvalue)
  })

  output$category <- renderUI({input$clear
    result <- first_search()

    if(cldcheck() != 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$Contract.Class == input$classdrop,]
    }

        if(tdcheck() != 0)
        {
          result <- result[result$Contract.Template == input$templatedrop,]
        }

        if(sdcheck() != 0)
        {
          result <- result[result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name == input$supplierdrop,]
        }
    y <- unique(result$SCM.Category)
    dropdown('categorydrop', y, value = ctdvalue)
  })

  output$template <- renderUI({input$clear
    result <- first_search()

    if(ctdcheck() != 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$SCM.Category == input$categorydrop,]
    }

    if(cldcheck() != 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$Contract.Class == input$classdrop,]
    }

      if(sdcheck() != 0)
      {
        result <- result[result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name == input$supplierdrop,]
      }
    y <- unique(result$Contract.Template)
    dropdown('templatedrop', y, value = tdvalue)
  })

  output$supplier <- renderUI({input$clear
    result <- first_search()

    if(ctdcheck() != 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$SCM.Category == input$categorydrop,]
    }

    if(tdcheck() != 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$Contract.Template == input$templatedrop,]
    }

    if(cldcheck() != 0)
    {
      result <- result[result$Contract.Class == input$classdrop,]
    }
    y <- unique(result$Emptoris.Supplier.Name)
    dropdown('supplierdrop', y, value = sdvalue)
  })
  }
```

By merely changing `value` (which is exactly the same as `selected` for `selectInput`) to the global variable, I was able to achieve Excel - like filtering.
 The caveat with this approach is that there has to be a reset button to set all the global variable to their initial state.
To anyone struggling with reactivity, I would strongly suggest using `shiny.reactlog` to understand the reactive flow of the shiny app.

Cheers!